# Easiest way to assign a static IP address for a LAMP server / VBox snapshot

Tags: server, virtualbox, lamp, resolv.conf, static-ip

I want to create a basic Ubuntu 12.04 LAMP server under VBox. Once I have it configured with a base Data set I want to Snapshot that and be able to hand it off to my development partners to use. Basically I want to be able to clone/snapshot a ready to use LAMP server.

I am under the impression I would want to assign a static IP / Hostname and then open port 3306 using iptables. I would then provide this info to anyone using this database server.

To that end I am installing Ubuntu Server 12.04 and LAMP and then following the standard tutorials on setting a static IP. I have etc/network/interfaces configured but when it comes to writing the nameserver entries in resolv.conf, I open it but the first two lines state not to edit that changes will be lost.

here is what I have in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface etho inet static
    address 192.168.1.155
    netmask 255.255.255.0   
    network 192.168.1.1
    gateway 50.43.32.1
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nameserver 184.16.33.54 184.16.4.22
```

When I attempt to restart the network I get an error stating:

```
Reconfiguring network interfaces
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0
                                                       [OK]
```

What would I edit to effect the hostname changes and better yet might there be an easier way to accomplish what I am after. I know I can edit my internal network to assign a static IP and I am doing that for a network storage device, but I would rather not rely on that interface to be there for others in this case.

Thanks for any the input and advice in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "effect the hostname changes"?

Comment: Thanks for the info in your answer. etho in my question is a typo. In my /etc/network/interfaces file it is eth0 as I only changed dhcp to static on that line and then added the network addressing, etc. below. I had tried dns-nameserver at one point. I went ahead and made the dns-nameserver change and restarted but got the same error. I will take a better look at your advice against what I have already tried. To answer your question regarding hostname changes. More or less how I bind the servername to the static IP addressing. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Note that the option name is `dns-nameservers`, not `dns-nameserver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The correct syntax for specifying nameserver addresses in `/etc/network/interfaces` is

   ```
   iface eth0 inet static
       ...
       dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
   ```
2. In your `/etc/network/interfaces` as quoted in your question you have named the interface `etho` rather than `eth0`.
3. You can omit the `network` option in `/etc/network/interfaces`. It is no longer needed or used.

After editing `/etc/network/interfaces` do the following to activate the changes.

```
    sudo ifdown eth0
    sudo ifup eth0
```